# Gameobject becomes a Cube when uploading it to Unity from Blender

Tags: unity, graphics, blender

I'm making a 3d mobile game, for one of my gamemodes i need "Hexagon" gameobject.

According to my research I can create unique gameobjects in blender. So I tried to make a hexagon and export it as an wavefront(.obj) but when uploading it to unity, all i can see was cube.

**Edit:** I've tried to export it as an FBX, Wavefront and even Blender file, but none of them works.

Comment: "I searched the whole internet" welp, I guess you've plumbed the full depth of human knowledge on the subject and hexagons must simply be impossible, then. On a more serious note: you and I both know this is possible, and that a search for hexagons in Unity turns up tons of leads. So, just saying "I didn't find anything" or "it didn't work" doesn't tell us enough to help you with your specific problem. What exact steps did you take in Blender to make your hexagon model? (Show us!) How did you configure your export settings? (Show us that too!)

Comment: [It's a 3 step process to do it with blender](https://pasteboard.co/I6KXgI0.png), did you delete the starting cube?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GYWTm1E8gV8 (That's the video tutorial that i tried to make hexagon model, i did every step properly.) And like i said i've tried another export options too, like .fbx-.obj.

Comment: And i've deleted the starting cube

Comment: If every step you did was correct, then you'd have the desired outcome. Since you don't have the desired outcome, some step in the process was not correct. To be able to find that step, we need you to edit your question to walk us through what you did.. Otherwise all we can say is "do what the tutorial did, that demonstrably works" which isn't any help to you.

Comment: @AmonRa'sChannel Apart from that tutorial being terrible (just create a cylinder), you shouldn't have problems with it. 1.) Go into blender 2.) delete the cube 3.) create a new cylinder 4.) set vertices to 6. 5.) save the model to your desktop 6.) open unity 7.) drag the hexagon file from your desktop into the unity asset folder 8.) drag the object from the asset folder into the scene

Comment: Look i think there is something wrong about saving the file, 'cause when i drag and drop the object to the scene it's just a cube

Comment: http://prntscr.com/n24o4z look at it

Comment: Okay i figured it out... I was deleting everything in the first scene by pressing "9" and delete, but i realized the cube, camera and lamp was in the inspector panel in the blender. I've deleted them and saved it and right now it works fine

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please feel free to post your solution as an Answer. This can help other new Blender/Unity users who might make the same mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by deleting start-up objects in the blender by simply selecting them and pressing "X".